# I was riding my bike when I saw my friend or I had been riding my bike when I saw my friend?

Tags: grammar, tenses

What is the difference between these two sentence? Does had been indicate that the action now has been interrupted? Or is more context required to differentiate the two?

1. I *was* riding my bike when I saw my friend
2. I *had been* riding my bike when I saw my friend

Comment: (1) is idiomatic. (2) sounds better with context (which could be internal: 'I had been riding my bike for quite some time when I saw my friend').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to existing answers and comments I would say that "I was riding my bike when I saw my friend" implies that the speaker was actually riding their bike when they saw their friend whereas "I had been riding my bike when I saw my friend" implies that they had, at a minimum, dismounted and might even have put the bike away before they saw the friend. "Had been" implies a completed action in the past whereas "was" implies a continuous, uncompleted, action in the past.

Compare with "I was in the shower when the phone rang." and "I had been in the shower when the phone rang". In the first case the speaker probably missed the call, in the second they probably answered it but with a towel wrapped around them.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that the second one shows that the person saw his/her friend when he/she was about to finish cycling. So the first one just shows that one action happened in a continuous action and the other one shows that the cycling was almost finish like about 80 percent(not actual number) of it was done.

Answer (score 0):

*Had been* shifts the center of gravity to the exact timeline. You emphasize that you had already been on your way when you saw your friend looking for you, because she was late for a cycling date.

“I *was* cycling” may carry the same meaning in regular speech if you intone it properly. But in formal writing, say in a court deposition, it should be as above.